# Swift: how to wrap `completion` into an async/await?

Tags: swift, asynchronous, async-await, swift-concurrency

I have a callback based API.

```
func start(_ completion: @escaping () -> Void)
```

I'd like to write an async/await wrapper on top of that API, deferring the implementation to original callback based API.

```
func start() async {
    let task = Task()
    start { 
        task.fulfill()
    }
    
    return await task
}
```

Obviously, this code doesn't connect - it's not real, there is no method `fulfill` on `Task`.

Question: is there a way to use unstructured concurrency in Swift so that it would help me achieve this?

Comment: You are looking for [continuations](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/concurrency/how-to-use-continuations-to-convert-completion-handlers-into-async-functions)

Comment: Oh... hah, that was quite not very long... I will gladly accept this as the right answer, if you put copy paste this as an answer... :)

Comment: @George could you help me with [that](https://stackoverflow.com/q/75475683/2725435) question? It was marked as a similar, but I got confused.

Comment: @BartłomiejSemańczyk I recommend reading the HWS article linked in my answer below, and also the documentation [here](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/checkedcontinuation). There are many resume methods, each one suiting individual cases.

Answer (score 19, accepted):

You are looking for [continuations](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/concurrency/how-to-use-continuations-to-convert-completion-handlers-into-async-functions).

Here is how to use it in your example:

```
func start() async {
    await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
        start(continuation.resume)
    }
}
```