# Using `async` method synchronously

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swift-concurrency

I am moving some of my asynchronous functions to the new Swift Concurrency mechanism. At some point, I transform a method with a completion handler to a synchronous method using `DispatchGroup` (it can looks weird but this is because I use this method in an `Operation`):

```swift
func myMethodSync() -> String {
    var result: String!
    let group = DispatchGroup()
    group.enter()
    myMethod { asyncResult
        result = asyncResult
        group.leave()
    }
    group.wait()
    return result
}
```

I'd like to do the same using `async`/`await`. However when simply converting the code, I get a compiler error:

> Mutation of captured var 'result' in concurrently-executing code

Is there any other way of achieving this via the new APIs?

Comment: Unclear. When you say `await` you stop and wait. Isn't that exactly what your (incorrect) dispatch group code was intended to do? So there's no problem to solve.

Comment: Is there missing `group.wait()` before return?

Comment: Either make `myMethod` also `async` to `await`the result or work with a `Continuation`. `DispatchGroup` has nothing to do with Swift Concurrency. And stop declaring variables as implicit unwrapped optionals in a function

Comment: I think you don't need `myMethodSync` any more. Paradigma of Concurrency is to not block threads.

Comment: @Cy-4AH Sorry, fixed my example. And yes I do need `myMethodSync` because I need to use it in a synchronous context (which is an `Operation` object)

Comment: @Florentin you still can use asynchronous operations in the synchronous context. I think it's better to override `isExecuting`, `isFinished` than locking thread with `group.wait()`

Comment: @Cy-4AH I see, it's interesting. I'll think about it, thanks!

Comment: @Florentin This isn't the best way to do it. Swift concurrency has [continuations](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/concurrency/how-to-use-continuations-to-convert-completion-handlers-into-async-functions) as @ vadian says, _exactly_ for this purpose. I have an answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69903198/9607863) about it. Then either make your method `async` (best choice) or wrap it in a `Task`. You can't synchronously return an asynchronous value.