# Invalid conversion from throwing function of type to non-throwing function type-trying to wrap a 'continuation' in an await/async that throws an error

Tags: swiftui, azure-ad-b2c

I am trying to wrap a completion function with an await/async and found a few [so questions/answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69902995/swift-how-to-wrap-completion-into-an-async-await) and [a post](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/concurrency/how-to-use-continuations-to-convert-completion-handlers-into-async-functions) which helped. Even [one covering wrapping](https://www.hackingwithswift.com/quick-start/concurrency/how-to-create-continuations-that-can-throw-errors) a continuation which throws errors, but I want to wrap a continuation which bundles the error into the result and instead throw it. Here is my attempt:

```
func silentRefreshAsync(msalApplication: MSALPublicClientApplication) async throws -> RefreshedToken? {

    await withCheckedContinuation { continuation in
        silentRefresh(msalApplication: msalApplication) {result in
                
            switch result {
            case .failure(let error):
                print("\(error)")
                throw error
            case.success(let token):
                continuation.resume(returning: token)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I get the error:

> Invalid conversion from throwing function of type
> '(Result<RefreshedToken, any Error>) throws -> Void' to non-throwing
> function type '(Result<RefreshedToken, any Error>) -> Void'

I'm new to SwiftUI and any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try changing `withCheckedContinuation` with `withCheckedThrowingContinuation`, as your function declaration indicates that the function can throw.